# Unicode glyphs not combined properly on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, unicode, glyph

**Problem:** Javanese Script (using [Google's Noto Sans Javanese font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-java)) rendered and "combined" properly on HTML, but **not** on Windows Forms Application (C# .NET, Visual Studio 2017).

*Edit:* My computer uses Windows 7, 64-bit.

[Noto Sans Javanese direct download link (.zip)](https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoSansJavanese-unhinted.zip)

---

**Glyphs Used**

There are many cases to show that the glyphs are not combined properly, but here's one example I used:

1. JAVANESE LETTER NA, U+A9A4, #43428;
2. JAVANESE PANGKON, U+A9C0, #43456;
3. JAVANESE LETTER TA, U+A9A0, #43424;
4. JAVANESE VOWEL SIGN PEPET, U+A9BC, #43452;

[Javanese Script Unicode Specification direct download link (.pdf)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA980.pdf)

---

**Correct/desired behaviour**

Four of these glyphs should be "combined", becoming one character

*HTML code:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    .javanese {
    font-family: "Noto Sans Javanese";
    font-size: 66px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="javanese">ꦤ꧀ꦠꦼ</div>
    <div class="javanese">&#43428;&#43456;&#43424;&#43452;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*HTML result:*

[image: Correct rendering of Javanese Script on HTML]

---

**Incorrect rendering on Windows Forms (C# .NET)**

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community, creating a Windows Forms Desktop Application.
Label components are using the "Noto Sans Javenese" font.

*C# code:*

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.label1.Text = "\uA9A4\uA9C0\uA9A0\uA9BC";
            this.label2.Text = "ꦤ꧀ꦠꦼ"; // Copied from HTML

            // this one is rendered correctly
            // Thai character "ko kai" (U+0E01) and combining characters "mai tho" (U+0E49).
            this.label3.Text = "\u0E01\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49\u0E49";
        }
    }
}
```

*C# result:*

[image: Incorrect rendering of Javanese script on Windows Form Application]

---

**Questions**

1. What is the reason of this behavior? Can someone explain?
2. What should I do to make the Javanese script "combined" correctly on Windows Form Application?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @downvoter: why? is this not a valid question?

Comment: This might be a valid question if it is some oddball rendering quirk that needs special care, so I will upvote it gladly, but it might also be a simple defect in Windows Forms. I suggest you also report it to Microsoft.

Comment: @Sander thanks! I just made [a thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33fb4f0c-36a2-411a-97ba-6c0572badd10/unicode-glyphs-not-combined-properly-on-windows-forms?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup?  I just reproduced your project and got output you describe as correct: http://i.imgur.com/G7lxeeP.png   --- (edit to add: just noticed your screenshots look like they're coming from Windows 7, that might be the difference.  One thing to try is to set the UseCompatibleTextRendering property on the labels to 'true'.  This will force the labels to use GDI+ text rendering, which, on older versions of Windows, supports advanced scripts better.)

Comment: @TimothyFries Thank you for reproducing my problem. Yes, I am using Windows 7. I have tried setting `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `true`, but the result is still incorrect, [here's the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ZxmMZAi.png). I agree with you that Win 7 might be a problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten few options and insights to help resolve this problem. Apparently, this is only a problem with Windows Forms on Windows 7.

So far, my options are:

1. Switch to WPF Application (best option, in my opinion)
2. Use [WPF Composite Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms) inside Windows Forms
3. Render as bitmap using third-party libraries, for example: [HarfBuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/)

---

Here are the sources, credits goes to all respective authors:

---

1. [cheong00](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/cheong00/?ws=usercard-mini) posted a great explanation on [a MSDN Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33fb4f0c-36a2-411a-97ba-6c0572badd10/unicode-glyphs-not-combined-properly-on-windows-forms?forum=netfxbcl):

> Since [Win7 has Unicode 5.1 support only](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2009/07/07/engineering-windows-7-for-a-global-market/) and [the character \uA9A4 falls in Unicode 5.2 range](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9a4/index.htm), the GDI+ text rendering function may not be able to handle the glyph hints correctly. (I'm not expert on i18n issues, so don't know whether special glyph hint support is needed)
>
> Since IE and other web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox all comes with their own font rendering engine, they're not subject to GDI+ rendering limitations.
>
> Btw, also tested setting "UseCompatibleTextRendering" to true does not help either.
>
> On the other hand, WPF forms does render the text correctly. So consider changing it to WPF application, or replace necessary controls with [WinForm hosted WPF controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms).

---

2. [u/GoogleBingLady](https://www.reddit.com/user/GoogleBingLady) posted an insight on [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6rxef1/unicode_glyphs_not_combined_properly_on_windows/dl8paha/):

> Font shaping (Bidirectionality, Context-based shaping, ligatures, positioning & reordering) is a very, very complex topic. Although I'd be surprised, it may be that Windows Forms do not support font shaping.
>
> A workaround would be to use a library like HarfBuzz, render the result to a bitmap and then display that bitmap. See http://behdad.org/text/ for details.
>
> In fact, your problem is described here on page 8: http://www.panl10n.net/Presentations/Cambodia/Pema/LocalizationofLinux(Bhutan).pdf

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not support Javanese shaping. Shaping support for Javanese was added in Windows 8.1.