# Arabic ligatures glyphs on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, glyph, ligature

I using `GetGlyphOutline` (WinApi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphoutlinew) to generate a font, but I ran into a problem with more complex Arabic Unicode.

example:
I have four characters: ا (U+0627) - ل (U+0644) - ل (U+0644) - ه (U+0647)
after generating glyphs for them the texts look exactly like single glyphs (characters), but in this case they should be replaced with a specific glyph that looks like this الله (here we still have 4x characters).
I know this character is also as a separate character in unicode as one character ﷲ, https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FDF2 but as far as I know it is in the unicode table for historical (compatibility) reasons and should be modeled / used on the unfolded form (i.e. 4 characters)

Is there any possibility to generate a glyph for four characters (ا (U+0627) - ل (U+0644) - ل (U+0644) - ه (U+0647)) to make it look like this one (ﷲ) ?

Or is it possible to convert these four Unicode ((U+0627)+(U+0644)+(U+0644)+(U+0647)) characters into one Unicode (U+FDF2)?

Comment: What you're looking for is _font shaping_, which is far from trivial and is not as simple as replacing Unicode code points with Unicode code points.  See, for example, the _Harfbuzz_ library.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529938/unicode-glyphs-not-combined-properly-on-windows-forms