# PictureBox control "blinking" when changing BorderStyle in code

Tags: c#, windows-10, picturebox, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing a Windows Desktop Application using C# in VS 2022 on Windows 10. I'm developing for a touch screen and want the UI to be very intuitive and give good feedback because the user(s) will likely be tech-averse.  On several of the forms I'm using a PictureBox as a button because I like the visual effects better.  I can get a nice "button pressed" effect by using the MouseDown and MouseUp events to change the border style of the PictureBox to Fixed3D (on mouse down) and back to None (on mouse up).  The only issue is that the PictureBox image "blinks" when I do this, like the control is clearing the image out and reloading it or something.

My code is rather trivial, but I'll post it here anyway just in case:

```
        private void Button_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }

        private void Button_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        }
```

Comment: That is inevitable, BorderStyle is a "difficult" property.  Difficult because it can only be specified when the control window gets created.  Winforms has a rather heroic workaround for that, it knows how to destroy and re-create the window on-the-fly.  But with the inevitable visible side-effect of the window disappearing and re-appearing.  Many possible workarounds, you'd certainly consider changing the Image property to indicate state.  And ensuring that the image is an exact fit so doesn't have to be resized while painting.  And uses the 32bppPArgb pixel format, 10x faster than any other.

Comment: Thank you Hans.  Could you elaborate a little bit please?  What did you have in mind for changing the image property to indicate a button pressed state?

Comment: No idea why you liked the BorderStyle, but of course you could make that part of the image and create the PB without a border.  Shadow effects of released vs pressed are also very common, let your imagination run wild.

Comment: @TheoDoc2013 I know you have a good reason for saying that you like the `PictureBox` visual styles better but could you specify exactly why that is? `Button` already has `MouseOver` and `MouseDown` styles out of the box.  To maximize the benefit, you could set your button icons using glyphs from a [Fontello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552477/5438626) font that you design yourself. Or, you could take full control using owner-draw with [ButtonRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: Well, IVSoftware, I certainly could be missing something.  What I liked about turning the BorderStyle of the PictureBox to 3D and back to None was the visual effect of pressing a button.  It makes it look like it has been depressed for a moment.  On a Button control, the user press just makes the background change color, which is not what I'm looking for.  That said, I will look into using ButtonRenderer as you suggest.  That might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Got it. So definitely looking for that 3D-depth effect. Thank you, that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to solving your blinking problem another way, consider this reusable `CustomButton` class that lets you use your own custom image to depict the 3D `pressed` state. The icons are superimposed using the `Text` property and a custom font containing glyphs (making it easy to change their size and color). When the button is *not* pressed, system theme takes over *or* you could unset the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` property to additionally customize things like `OnMouseHover`.

[image: focused pressed hovered states]

---

`CustomButton` inherits from `Button`and has a `PrivateFontCollection` giving it access to a **.ttf** file containing glyphs. This particular **flashlight-filter-history-favorite-search.ttf** is one I designed for my own project using the [Fontello](https://fontello.com) open-source icon font generator.

```
public CustomButton()
{
    UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    refCount++;
}
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (!DesignMode) initFont();
}
private void initFont()
{
    if (privateFontCollection == null)
    {
        privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
            "Fonts",
            "flashlight-filter-history-favorite-search.ttf");
        privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(path);
        var fontFamily = privateFontCollection.Families[0];
        GlyphFontUp = new Font(fontFamily, 16F);
        GlyphFontDown = new Font(fontFamily, 15F);
    }
    Font = GlyphFontUp;
    ForeColor = GlyphColorUp;
}
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = null;
public static Font GlyphFontUp { get; private set; } = null;
public static Font GlyphFontDown { get; private set; } = null;
public static Color GlyphColorUp { get; } = Color.Teal;
public static Color GlyphColorDown { get; } = Color.DarkCyan;

private static int refCount = 0;
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        refCount--;
        if (refCount == 0)
        {
            GlyphFontUp?.Dispose();
            privateFontCollection?.Dispose();
        }
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

---

When the mouse is *down* the button has an image, the icon is smaller, and the icon color changes. When the mouse comes *up* the image is removed and everything goes back to normal.

```
partial class CustomButton : Button
{
   protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Image = new Bitmap(Resources.buttonDown, Size);
        Font = GlyphFontDown;
        ForeColor = GlyphColorDown;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        Font = GlyphFontUp;
        ForeColor = GlyphColorUp;
        Image = null;
    }
}
```

The `buttonDown` image is just something I drew myself. I'm pretty sure you could do better!

[image: 3d button down image]

---

The `CustomButton` class can be swapped out in the **MainForm.Designer.cs** file.

```
// private System.Windows.Forms.Button customButton0;
   private intuitive_buttons.CustomButton customButton0;
```

---

This code assigns the various icons to the buttons:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Assign the icons to the buttons
        customButton0.Text = "\uE800";
        customButton1.Text = "\uE801";
        customButton2.Text = "\uE802";
        customButton3.Text = "\uE803";
        customButton4.Text = "\uE804";
    }
}
```

Hope this at least gives you a few ideas to try.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/intuitive_button.git) this sample. See what you think!

Comment: Thanks very much IV - this has great possibilities.  I'll give it a try!